# Show that $C^1[a,b]$ with the uniform norm is not a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Consider the normed vector space $(C^1[a,b],||\cdot||_{\infty})$, we have to prove that it is not Banach.

From theory a space is Banach if it is complete, ie if every Cauchy sequence in the space converges to an element of the same space.

So what we have to do is:

- find a Cauchy sequence in the space
- show that the squence does not converge to an element of the space

Consider $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and the sequence defined by $f_k(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1/k},\ k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since the argument of the root is always non-negative, the sequence is always differentiable and both $f_k$ and $f'_k$ are continuous. So $\{f_k\}\in C^1[-1,1]$.

Intuitively I see that $\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty} f_k(x)=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\notin C^1[-1,1]$, but I first have to show that the sequence is Cauchy.

From theory a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy iff $\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall m,n>N$ we have $||x_n-x_m||<\epsilon$.

In our case we have $||\sqrt{x^2+1/n}-\sqrt{x^2+1/m}||\le||\sqrt{x^2+1/n}||+||\sqrt{x^2+1/m}||$ (*).

The sum (*) should be less than $\epsilon$, so each term should be less than $\epsilon/2$.

Moreover, since we are working with the uniform norm and $||f||_{\infty}=max\{|f(x)|:x\in [a,b]\}$, I think that $||f_k(x)||_{\infty}=\sqrt{2}$ because $max\{x^2:x\in [-1,1]\}=1$ and $max\{1/k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}=1$. So the sum (*) should be less or equal to $2\sqrt{2}$.

How can I use these information to prove that $\{f_k\}$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: You don't want to throw away all the control by using that version of the triangle inequality. Try graphing the functions and see for what value(s) of $x$ the functions $f_n$ and $f_m$ are farthest apart.

Comment: I think is $0$ the value of $x$ for which $f_n$ and $f_m$ are farthest apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the triangle inequality like this is too coarse. We can proceed like this:

$$\|\sqrt{x^2+{1/n}}-\sqrt{x^2+{1/m}}\|=\left\|\frac{1/n-1/m}{\sqrt{x^2+{1/n}}+\sqrt{x^2+{1/m}}}\right\|= \\
= |1/n-1/m|\cdot\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+{1/n}}+\sqrt{x^2+{1/m}}}\right\|$$

Now, $|1/n-1/m|=\frac{|n-m|}{nm}$, and

$$\left\|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+{1/n}}+\sqrt{x^2+{1/m}}}\right\| = \frac{1}{1/\sqrt n+1/\sqrt m} = \frac{\sqrt{nm}}{\sqrt n + \sqrt m}$$

(the denominator is easily seen to be at minimum for $x=0$).

So, assuming $N<n<m$, the product is

$$\frac{|n-m|}{\sqrt{nm}(\sqrt n + \sqrt m)} \leq \frac{m}{\sqrt{nm}(\sqrt n + \sqrt m)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n/m}+1)}\leq \\
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$$

(since $\sqrt{n/m}+1 \geq 1$).

Solving $\frac{1}{\sqrt N}<\varepsilon$ gives $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$. Thus, for

$$n,m > \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$$

we get

$$\|\sqrt{x^2+{1/n}}-\sqrt{x^2+{1/m}}\| \leq \varepsilon$$

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, could you explain by words the conclusion? I see you found that $||\sqrt{x^2+1/n}-\sqrt{x^2+1/m}||$ is bounded by $1/\sqrt{N}$, with $N\in\mathbb{N}$, how does this show that the sequence is Cauchy?

Comment: @lisyarus He found that the $||f_n(x)-f_m(x)||\le 2\sqrt{2}$ that is a constant like yours $1/ \sqrt{N}$. What's the difference? I mean you both showed that the norm is bounded by a constant.

Comment: @GiacomoTabarelli $1/\sqrt N$ is not a constant - it depends on $N$.

Comment: @soundwave I updated the answer.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you very much, now is more clear. So basically, correct me if I'm wrong, to show that a sequence is Cauchy, we have to find a bound which depends on $N$ or which can let us tell something on $N$, so that we can then impose a condition on $n$ and $m$ ?

Comment: @soundwave The definition of a Cauchy sequence is "$\forall \varepsilon \exists N$ such that...", so you have to provide such $N$, given arbitrary $\varepsilon$. You are right - in practice this means finding a bound for $\|f_n-f_m\|$ that goes to zero as $N$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @lisyarus Thank you. Sorry I don't get your last sentence, you said that we have to find a bound for $||f_n-f_m||$ that goes to zero as $N$ goes to infinity. But, let's say that in this exercise we found that $||f_n-f_m||\le\sqrt{N}$ (instead of $1/\sqrt{N}$). The bound clearly goes to infinity for $N\rightarrow\infty$, but still we could say that from $\sqrt{N}=\epsilon$ we get $N=\epsilon^2$, thus for $n,m>\epsilon^2$ we get $||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @soundwave The problem is that $N$ is a natural number, so we can't really say $N=\varepsilon^2$. I've slightly fixed the answer so that it is less confusing.

Comment: @lisyarus Ah yes right it is a natural number. So what happens if we find that $||f_n-f_m||$ is bounded by $\sqrt{N}$ instead of $1/\sqrt{N}$?

Comment: @soundwave Well, we cannot say anything in this case. E.g. for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ there is no $N$ such that $\|f_n-f_m\| < \varepsilon$ - we only now that $\|f_n-f_m\| < \sqrt N$, and $\sqrt N$ is at least $1$.

Comment: @lisyarus Ah ok thanks, so in that case we could say that the sequence doest not converge, i.e. is not Cauchy?

Comment: @soundwave If the only thing we now is that $\|f_n-f_m\|<\sqrt N$, then we cannot conclude that the sequence is not Cauchy - probably we just got a very bad upper bound. To prove that a sequence is not Cauchy you have to prove that there is a $\varepsilon$ such that there is no $N$ such that for any $n,m >N $ we have $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @lisyarus Can we prove that a sequence is Cauchy with the Dominated Convergence Theorem? I mean in this case we have $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}f_n(x)=|x|=f(x)$ so the limit exists, to found the $g$ function that bounds our sequence I can proceed in that way, so I take $g = 2\sqrt{2}$ and it's clear that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$, applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem I get $\int\limits_a^b |f_n(x)-f|dx = 0$. So our sequence converges so it's Cauchy.